# Progess 4GL - Tune the query to increase the performance

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Below query updating more than 200k records and it takes 19 hours to finish it. How to tune it for increasing the performance?

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tdata no-undo
  field tptpart as character
  field tptsts  as character
  field ttype   as character.

empty TEMP-TABLE tdata.
INPUT FROM /sdd/aert/import.csv.

repeat:
 create tdata.
 IMPORT DELIMITER "," tdata.
end.
INPUT CLOSE.

FOR EACH tdata
  WHERE tptpart = "":
  DELETE tdata.
END.

etime(true).
FOR EACH tdata:
  FOR FIRST xx_mstr 
    WHERE xx_domain = "XX" 
    and xx_part = tptpart 
     exclusive-lock use-index xx_part:
    assign
      xx_mstr.xx_status = ttptsts
      xx_mstr.type = ttype.
  end.
   release xx_mstr.
  end.
  message "This took" ETIME "milliseconds" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know the definitions of the indexes that are defined for xx_mstr.

Comment: Further questions:
- How many records are there in xx_mstr?
- Are you sure the each part does only occur once in the csv and therefore in tdata? If parts can occur more than once you should change the code so that each record in xx_mstr is not written to more than one time. (Either by changing the outer loop to something like 
FOR EACH xx_mstr where ... break by xx_mstr.xx_part: if first-of(xx_mstr.xx_part) then find tdata ...
or by checking if the current tdata record is the last record for that part.
For both of these options you would have to add an index on tdata.tptpart.)

Answer (score 4):

There are several opportunities for performance improvement in your sample code:

- You are requesting an EXCLUSIVE-LOCK but you are also queueing to wait for it. That could very easily be the largest source of delay in this code
- You are committing updates one record at a time. When you do a lot of small updates that can stress the system, grouping updates into larger chunks can improve performance considerably
- Your temp-table is large and, if you have default startup parameters, is probably being written to disk rather than residing entirely in memory. You should look into increasing -Bt
- You are measuring the time for the entire process but you don't really know which portion of things is causing the long run time, finer grained logging would help pinpoint the specific problem
- USE-INDEX is overriding the compiler's ability to choose good indexes and without knowing the definition of available indexes we can't say if the one you have specified is appropriate. However, my experience is that the compiler is smarter about this than I am so I strongly advise letting the compiler pick

The code below may contain a few syntax errors, I don't have your database nor the contents of the csv file to work with but the general ideas should apply:

```
define temp-table tdata no-undo
  field tptpart   as character
  field tptsts    as character
  field ttype     as character
.

define variable chunks           as integer no-undo.
define variable recordWasUpdated as integer no-undo.
define variable recordWasLocked  as integer no-undo.

empty temp-table tdata.

etime( true ).

input from "/sdd/aert/import.csv".              /* unquoted file names are a "worst practice", don't do that!   */
repeat:
  create tdata.
  import delimiter "," tdata.
  if tdata.tptpart = "" then                    /* delete invalid records right away, no need for a separate loop to do that */
    delete tdata.
end.
input close.

/* report time to load the temp-table just in case that is longer than expected
 *
 * this looks like it might be a large temp-table (200,000 rows) so you might
 * want to review the -Bt client startup parameter and make sure that it
 * is adequate
 */

message "loading tdata took:" etime "milliseconds" view-as alert-box.

/* the main loop
 *
 * apply updates from the temp-table
 *   delete records from the TT as updates succeed
 *
 * repeat until there are no records being locked (in other words, all updates succeeded, and the temp-table should be empty now)
 *
 */

do while true:

  etime( true ).
  recordWasLocked = 0.
  recordWasUpdated = 0.
  chunks = 0.

  /* this outer transaction block will group records into larger chunks to be committed
   * doing so reduces write() synchronous operations on the server and improves performance
   * of large updates, chunks of 100 records is usually a decent balance between better
   * performance and larger -L (lock table) usage
   */

  chunkLoop: do while true transaction:

    chunks = chunks + 1.

    for each tdata:

      /* the FOR which was formerly here is almost certainly not appropriate,
       * FIND is the proper statement to find a single record
       *
       * USE-INDEX is also almost always inapprpropriate,
       * let the compiler choose the index unless you have a VERY
       * good reason to think that you are smarter than the
       * compiler, and if do think that, please document your
       * reasoning and the test cases that support your opinion
       *
       * FIRST is also probably not appropriate - especially if
       * the record is uniquely identified by the combination of
       * xx_domain and xx_part. If that is NOT unique then these
       * updates don't make much sense anyway. You would be
       * introducing some pretty serious logical inconsistenties
       *
       * Lack of NO-WAIT means that you will be waiting in a
       * queue for the EXCLUSIVE-LOCK request to be granted.
       * Or, it will fail entirely when the -lkwtmo parameter
       * times out. This is very likely where most of your long
       * run time is coming from
       */

      find xx_mstr exclusive-lock where xx_domain = "xx" and xx_part = tptpart no-wait.

      if available( xx_mstr ) then
        do:
          assign
            xx_mstr.xx_status = ttptsts
            xx_mstr.type = ttype
          .
          delete tdata.
          recordWasUpdated = recordWasUpdated + 1.

          /* commit a group of (up to) 100 records
           */

          if recordWasUpdated modulo 100 = 0 then next chunkLoop.

        end.
       else
        do:
          recordWasLocked = recordWasLocked + 1.
        end.

      /* RELEASE is neither necessary nor helpful
       */

    end.

    leave chunkLoop.

  end.  /* chunkLoop */

  /* this will occur as many time as neccessary until all updates are applied
   */

  message
    substitute( "&1 records were updated in &2 chunks of updates which took &3 milliseconds, &4 records were locked and need to be retried.", recordWasUpdated, chunks, etime, recordWasLocked )
    view-as alert-box
  .

  if recordWasLocked = 0 then leave.

  /* if there were > 0 locked records loop around and retry the leftovers...
   */

end.
```

Answer (score 3):

I would look, first, at the `USE-INDEX` clause. Is that index *really* the index that can get that xx_mstr record fastest?

If you compile this code with the `XREF` (or `XML-XREF`) option , you can see which indexes the compiler will use (look for lines with `SEARCH`). If you remove the `USE-INDEX`, what index will be used? Will that find the records faster?

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion, how many fields are in the table? You can only loop selecting the fields that you need.

For example:

```
FOR EACH tdata FIELDS(tptpart ttptsts ttype) NO-LOCK:
  FOR FIRST xx_mstr 
    WHERE xx_domain = "XX" 
    and xx_part = tptpart 
    FIELDS (xx_domain xx_part xx_status type)
     exclusive-lock use-index xx_part:
    assign
      xx_mstr.xx_status = ttptsts
      xx_mstr.type = ttype.
  end.
   release xx_mstr.
  end.
```

This method increases the reading speed, because you're making sure that is only after the fields you need, leaving the rest untouched.

And don't forget the NO-LOCK on the first FOR EACH, otherwise if not configured, it will search with SHARE-LOCK.

Comment: I´m pretty sure that the FIELDS phrase doesn't help if you fetch the records in exclusive-lock. Also since only a single record is fetched at a time the FIELDS phrase won´t help much anyway.
A FIELDS phrase for a temp-table also doesn´t help.